# Chrome Devtools, why the console filter icon is red?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I haven't seen it before but my console filter is red, on Chrome devtools, everything is working as expected, I have searched without results, what is the meaning of that..[image]

Chrome version: 57.0.2987.98

Comment: Don't worry, the console toolbar is completely redesigned in the upcoming Chrome 58-59 so there'll be no disturbing red colors.

Comment: So it is a version design, why it is in red? It doesn't affect the behavior but it's outstanding....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Red icon suggests non-default settings of the filters.

The default state for filters is with 'Hide network' unchecked and 'Hide violations' checked. In this state filter icon is 'blue' when filter menu is expanded and 'gray' when it's collapsed.

Expanded:
[image: expanded DevTools console filters menu with default settings]

Collapsed:
[image: collapsed DevTools console filters menu with default settings]